# Rails -v gives error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
gem list
```

says I have

rails (2.3.5, 2.3.2)

but when I give

```
rails -v
```

it spits out an error

```
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:578:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem test-spec (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:134:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:158:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:157:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:157:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:158:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:157:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:157:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:158:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:157:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:157:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:49:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

Any Possible Solutions?

Comment: Try running gem install rails again and then do rails -v

Comment: By the way, this is the best tutorial I've found http://railsapps.github.io/installing-rails.html#gems

Comment: I'd nix everything and start with installing rvm: http://rvm.io (from experience strange or old installs of ruby will break things at some point, better to just start with a clean rvm managed ruby)

Comment: Yup agreed. Just go to "Getting Started" in the guide I posted and Daniel Kehoe will walk you through the RVM install for your system.

Comment: how did you install Ruby? e.g. via a RPM? via RVM? or is it manually compiled?

Comment: I am sshing into a live web server which provides a rails app. The rails app is working fine. Only thing when I give rails -v, the above error is what I get.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should tell what steps you followed to install ruby and rails ..

use

> $ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
>   --autolibs=enabled # Or, --ruby=1.9.3

check if rvm requirements left ..

> rvm requirements

then use

> gem install rails -v version

and also u can refer

> https://rvm.io/

Comment: i am ssh ing into a remote server where rails is already installed. Also its a live webserver for a rails app. So I am not sure whether I should be re installing stuff.